# PrimeFaces Datatable column lines not in one line

Tags: primefaces, datatable, rowexpansion

I have the following problem in a pf4 application. I have a Datatable with expandable rows, in this expandable rows we added a tabview, and in one of these tabs i added a Table again. Now the column rows don't keep in one line, this looks very strange as you can see [here](http://i59.tinypic.com/zkiix0.png). Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
<p:dataTable style="width:100%"
                                                            value="#{orderOverview.selectedOrder.orderPositions}"
                                                            var="orderPosition" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="200"
                                                            emptyMessage="#{msgs['general.noEntriesFound']}">
                                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['general.brand']}">
                                                                <p:outputLabel
                                                                    value="#{orderOverview.selectedOrder.cargoMap.get(orderPosition.cargoId).brand}" />
                                                            </p:column>
                                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['general.type']}">
                                                                <p:outputLabel
                                                                    value="#{orderOverview.selectedOrder.cargoMap.get(orderPosition.cargoId).type}" />
                                                            </p:column>
                                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['general.model']}">
                                                                <p:outputLabel
                                                                    value="#{orderOverview.selectedOrder.cargoMap.get(orderPosition.cargoId).model.modelNameWithManufacturerDate}" />
                                                            </p:column>
                                                            <p:column style="width:20px">
                                                                <p:commandLink id="extras"
                                                                    rendered="#{orderOverview.selectedOrder.cargoMap.get(orderPosition.cargoId).extras != msgs['offer.noExtras']}"
                                                                    styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-lightbulb" />
                                                                <p:tooltip for="extras"
                                                                    value="Extras: #{orderOverview.selectedOrder.cargoMap.get(orderPosition.cargoId).extras}" />
                                                            </p:column>
                                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['order.vin617OrEmpty']}"
                                                                style="width: 142px;">
                                                                <p:outputLabel
                                                                    value="#{orderOverview.formatCargoId(orderOverview.selectedOrder.cargoMap.get(orderPosition.cargoId).cargo.cargoId)}" />
                                                            </p:column>
                                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['order.jobNumber']}">
                                                                <p:outputLabel
                                                                    value="#{orderOverview.selectedOrder.cargoMap.get(orderPosition.cargoId).cargo.jobNumber}" />
                                                            </p:column>
                                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['order.registrationNr']}">
                                                                <p:outputLabel
                                                                    value="#{orderOverview.selectedOrder.cargoMap.get(orderPosition.cargoId).cargo.registrationNumber}" />
                                                            </p:column>
                                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['general.price']}"
                                                                rendered="#{orderOverview.selectedOrder.extendedCustomer}"
                                                                style="padding:0px;width:120px">
                                                                <p:panelGrid style="margin:0px">
                                                                    <p:row>
                                                                        <p:column style="padding:0px;width:15px;border:none">
                                                                            <p:commandLink id="tooltipPrice" style="margin:0px"
                                                                                styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-lightbulb" />
                                                                        </p:column>
                                                                        <p:column
                                                                            style="border:none;padding-left: 0px; padding-right:0px">
                                                                            <p:outputLabel
                                                                                value="#{orderPosition.price.price} #{orderPosition.price.currency}" />
                                                                        </p:column>
                                                                    </p:row>
                                                                </p:panelGrid>
                                                                <p:tooltip for="tooltipPrice"
                                                                    rendered="#{orderPosition.priceMatrixId != null}"
                                                                    value="#{msgs['general.contract']}: #{orderOverview.selectedOrder.priceMatrixMap.get(orderPosition.priceMatrixId).priceModel().contract.name}" />
                                                                <p:tooltip for="tooltipPrice"
                                                                    rendered="#{orderPosition.priceMatrixId == null}"
                                                                    value="#{msgs['order.enteredManually']}" />
                                                            </p:column>
                                                            <f:facet
                                                                name="#{orderOverview.selectedOrder.hasOffer() ? 'footer' : null}">
                                                                <p:panel style="text-align:right;"
                                                                    rendered="#{!orderOverview.selectedOrder.extendedCustomer}">
                                                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{msgs['offer.totalPrice']}:"
                                                                        style="color:white;" />
                                                                    <p:outputLabel
                                                                        value="#{orderOverview.selectedOrder.offer.totalPrice} #{orderOverview.selectedOrder.offer.currency}"
                                                                        style="color:white;">
                                                                        <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2"
                                                                            minFractionDigits="2" />
                                                                    </p:outputLabel>
                                                                </p:panel>
                                                            </f:facet>
                                                        </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Do you can write xhtml and log when xhtml is created? It´s usually when you use `p:columnGroup` and your `p:dataTable` have **scroll** or something in `p:columns` are **nullPointerException**

Comment: how can I post the log when the xhtml is created?

Comment: What IDE are you using??

Comment: Copy your xhtml in question

Comment: solved it myself, i did use some padding on one column, this was the issue.